# Is this telephone company's terms of usage common or unfair?

Tags: united-states, terms-of-service, is-x-legal, fcc, unfair-terms

Though many think the price is good, their policy does mean your telephone service is subject to change.

Is this even legal to enforce per FCC?

> reserves the right to reclaim any phone number from Customer’s Account if Customer does not send sufficient traffic over that phone number such that the phone number is unutilized or underutilized, as defined by any local, federal, and/or national regulatory agency and/or governmental organization with oversight over the relevant phone number and numbering plan. If  seeks to reclaim a phone number from Customer’s Account, excluding suspended, terminated, and trial accounts,  will provide at least two weeks’ advance notice via email where possible within commercial reason, except where  is prevented from doing so by the applicable regulatory agency or governmental organization.  also reserves the right to reclaim phone numbers from accounts suspended for failure to pay and/or suspended for suspected fraud. Customer may not transfer or assign the telephone numbers  provides to Customer unless otherwise mutually agreed by the Parties in writing.

Comment: It would not surprise me if your current phone is covered under a similar term.

Comment: In UK it was common for a mobile (cell) phone 'Pay-As-You-Go' account (no rental fee) to be cancelled if it was not used in a 6-month period, and the number reclaimed. The issuing company would be getting no revenue from you, and you are hogging a number. There is a finite range of numbers available.

Comment: @WeatherVane in my experience it's common to reclaim the number if the credit isn't topped up periodically, but you can keep the number without using it for as long as you want as long as you keep paying for it.